# How Postgres/ANSI SQL systems relate 'count' aggregates to GROUP BY fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, ansi-sql

I'm trying to understand both the `group by` and the `count(*)` in the following SQL query:

```
select Fizz.countryId, Buzz.kindId, Buzz.razId, count(*)
from Foo
  join Buzz on Foo.BuzzId = Buzz.id
  join Fizz on Foo.FizzId = Fizz.id
where
  Foo.borrowed > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 months'
group by
  Fizz.countryId, Buzz.kindId, Buzz.razId;
```

So we're joining three tables: `Fizz`, `Buzz` and `Foo`. Then we're filtering out records out of that joined table
whose `Foo.borrowed` field is older than 6 months. But what I'm not understanding is how `count(*)` is being calculated
and how it relates to the fields mentioned in the `group by` clause. **Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the result only one row will be shown for every distinct combination of `Fizz.countryId, Buzz.kindId, Buzz.razId`. That's what `group by` does.

Therefore, each resulting row may represent many *original rows*. How many? `count(*)` tells you.